# How can I avoid that msal PublicClientApplication loads acquire_token_interactive more that once?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, msal

I have a python script that I run over and over again, the script includes the use of:

```
app = PublicClientApplication(CLIENT_ID, authority=AUTHORITY)
result = app.acquire_token_interactive(scopes=[SCOPE])
```

This opens a window in my internet browser. I only want this to happen the first time I run the script. Any ideas on how to not run that part of my code the next time I run it?

I don't believe using `acquire_token_silent` is an alternative due to internal company rules.

Comment: You have to use `acquire_token_silent` to login only once and get token automatically for next attempts that stores token in cache. If you can't use it, switch to other flows like client credentials or username  password flow that does not involve any user interaction. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77153291/how-to-avoid-pop-up-tag-in-browser-while-getting-access-token-with-using-msal-in/77221863#77221863

Answer (score 0):

> If you prefer signing in only once and getting access token in next attempts automatically, you have to use `acquire_token_silent` method that retrieves token from cache of previous sign in.

Alternatively, you can switch to other authentication flows like **client credentials** flow that does not involve any user interaction and generates token on behalf of application.

To get the access token using client credentials flow, you need to grant API permissions of **Application** type:

[image]

Now, I used below python code and got **access token** successfully in response like this:

```py
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication

clientID = "clientID"
clientSecret = "secret"
scopes= ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"] 
tenantID = "tenantID"
authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID

app = ConfidentialClientApplication(clientID,clientSecret,authority=authority)
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)
access_token = result.get("access_token")
print(access_token)
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded this token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) website, I got **`aud`** and **`roles`** claims with **valid** values:

[image]

**Reference:**
[azure - How to avoid pop up tag in browser while getting access token with using MSAL in python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77153291/how-to-avoid-pop-up-tag-in-browser-while-getting-access-token-with-using-msal-in/77221863#77221863)