# PowerBI Access to my Application users without needing them to login again

Tags: python-3.x, azure, powerbi, azure-active-directory

We have a backend application, Our objective is to enable users, upon logging into our application, to effortlessly access Power BI without the necessity of re-entering credentials in the Power BI platform.

Is there any ways like OIDC, generating a temp access token to access the platform.

Comment: Could you confirm whether your requirement is to generate access token without user interaction?

Comment: Yes, in search of ways that require less intervention from our app users, to provide the private resources accessible to them

Comment: If you don't want user interaction, you can generate access token using client credentials flow and use it to call Power BI API.

Comment: @Sridevi also is there any way where we have Azure account for each user in our application (credentials will be managed by us), so that we can support all services like Power BI, teams, etc with those credentials like appending the token to the URL should redirect to desired page without login again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To avoid user interaction, you can make use of **client credentials** flow that generates token as a service principal.

I registered one Azure AD application and created one secret in it like this:

[image]

You must **enable** below option in *Admin portal* that allows service principal to call Power BI API:

[image]

Make sure to add created **app registration** as *Admin/Contributor* of Power BI workspace like this:

*Go to Power BI Portal -> Your Workspace -> Click on … -> Manage access -> +Add people or groups -> Search for Service Principal with name -> Admin*

[image]

Now, use below sample python code that generates **access token** using client credential flow without user interaction:

```py
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication

clientID = "appId"
clientSecret = "secret"
scopes= ["https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default"] 
tenantID = "tenantId"
authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID

app = ConfidentialClientApplication(clientID,clientSecret,authority=authority)
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)
access_token = result.get("access_token")
print(access_token)
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to call Power BI API with below modified code, I got **response** successfully like this:

```py
import requests

access_token = "token_from_above"
group_id = "xxxxxxx"

url = f"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group_id}/reports/"
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    report_data = response.json()
    print("Report Data:", report_data)
else:
    print("Error:", response.status_code, response.text)
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[azure - How to avoid pop up tag in browser while getting access token with using MSAL in python - Stack Overflow by **me**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77153291/how-to-avoid-pop-up-tag-in-browser-while-getting-access-token-with-using-msal-in/77221863#77221863)